# Popup dialog notification on top of every activity

Tags: android, push-notification, popup

I read a lot on this topic, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.
I need to show dialog box notification (Viber like) that is quite big, has some options (radio buttons and text fields) and you can exit just with an answer.

All in all, I don't need the simple notification or the new Heads-up Notification (they are small and are stacked away in some time). I also read something about a regular activity just made transparent to look like it shown on top of something, but didn't exactly understood the whole concept.

Also the app should run in the background because the notifications are send from server side and should be showed right away.

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads

Comment: also https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead

Comment: I saw the link that you send, but I don't need a "head" i would like to show a whole popup dialog with options as describe above.

Comment: yes with place of head you can use there transparent activity concept is same

Comment: @Nouman: please do not format things in code that are not actually code. Over-bolding and over-formatting is a problem on Stack Overflow anyway, and often does not actually make things more readable.

Comment: my dear i'll take care of this next time.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`:

> Allows an app to create windows using the type
>   TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, shown on top of all other apps. Very few
>   apps should use this permission; these windows are intended for
>   system-level interaction with the user.

By this way a `view` will be create above all others applications (even those applications you don't bellow). For that you will need a permission in your manifest file:

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

[Here is a link for more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom notification layout and display them, but they have certain size constraints that you cannot modify.

As for making an Activity appear as a notification or dialog. What you would do is give the Activity layout a transparent background so the actual children of the layout, will be the only things drawn on top of the previous activity you had running when the Activity started. This pattern is used for android sharing system, were a card slides up from the bottom of the screen providing several methods for sharing.

As for running in the background, what you'll wanna do is set up GCM to have your service notify devices when data is received and then in your app register a Broadcast receiver that should be fired when data has been received from GCM. Using GCM will allow the android system efficiently deliver messages to your device taking into account battery, network conditions and user settings regarding background work. Other solutions, such as having your own persistent connection constantly pulling your server for new data is highly discouraged. You can find several tutorials on how to set up GCM in your app.